# Can't Create Table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, create-table

I'm trying to create a table by executing the script in SP.

Portion of Creating Table:

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE #TEMPS' + 
    '( ID VARCHAR(100), ' +
    'CUR_SUPVR_ID VARCHAR(100), ' +
    'CUR_SUPVR_NAME VARCHAR(100), ' +
    'CUR_SUPVR_LVL VARCHAR(100) )'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

But the `#TEMPS` was not created. Any thought?

Comment: `Temp table` created `inside` **dynamic query** cannot be accessed `outside` of dynamic query

Comment: Also i don't see need of dynamic query here

Comment: #TEMPS name is in variable form. That is why I made it that way.

Comment: As i mentioned you cannot access outside of dynamic query. Try using global temp table it will work

Comment: ##TempTable can be accessed universally, as opposed to #TempTable is only accessible within session.

Comment: Also keep in mind that global temp table will fail when same code is executed in another session

Comment: @NoDisplayName given what you've said, if the name of the temp table is not in variable, like #TEMPS. What if two users will execute the SP that create the temp table at the same time? Will it create 2 #TEMPS for each user or first come first serve?

Comment: @Stuart - It will create two different temp tables with session append to the name internally. But it is not the case for global temp table

Comment: Given that, I guess static temp table name will do. The reason I made it dynamic is to avoid the error of creating the table due to its existance.

Comment: Which dbms is this for?